# ASP.NET WebAPI deployed to IIS: Access to web.config denied (IIS searches in wrong path)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI mixed project which runs just fine in the VS2012 development server. It has a standard MVC `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route, as well as an additional WebAPI route `api/{controller}/{id}`. Requests which start with `/api/...` are directed to WebAPI, the others to normal MVC.

When I deploy it to the local IIS, the normal MVC routes are working. However, `/api` calls to  WebAPI are resulting in the exception

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\web.config' is denied.
```

Then I tried to set the proper security permissions on the `inetpub` folder and its subfolders. This didn't help anything, and because the normal MVC requests are working, I don't suspect the problem to be security-related.

Then I started **Sysinternals Process Monitor** to see what `w3wp.exe` is doing during the request. As it turns out, IIS looks for `web.config` here:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\api\web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\api\mycontroller\web.config
```

Of course, there is no `web.config` there.

**How can I set up IIS to recognize both routes?**

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is a problem with your routing. the problem is the permissions given to IIS I run into this error from time to time. Depending on the app pool identity you are running under you need to provide permissions to that entity. Here is a link to a very thorough explanation

[IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions)

Basically right click your project folder, go to properties, click the security tab and and you will see Group or user names. These are the allowed entities to perform read and/or write actions to that directory. Click Edit then Add; from here you will then "Enter the object names to select" typically IIS follows under IIS_IUSRS again this depends on your app pool configuration from here you should move on from the error mentioned!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that. Why do the normal MVC routes work if it's a security problem? And why does IIS access the `web.config` in the wrong folder?

Comment: Their are a number of reasons why IIS is trying to access the wrong folder. Here check out this [Q and A][1] .[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634939/asp-net-using-wrong-web-config-for-virtual-directory